# I am receiving the error "Bind variables only allowed in Apex Code [MALFORMED QUERY]" when testing a SOQL statement called from Jitterbit

Tags: salesforce, soql, jitterbit

We are using Jitterbit to query records from Salesforce, but we are running into an issue. In the query condition statement I am comparing two fields from the Salesforce table. When I go to test the query, it gives me the error "Bind variables only allowed in Apex Code [MALFORMED QUERY]".

Here is an example of the query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Price_Agreement_Item__c WHERE Approved_Date__c > Last_Upload_Date__c
```

The fields `Approved_Date__c` and `Last_Upload_Date__c` are both contained in Salesforce table `Price_Agreement_Item__c`. How does one create a SOQL statement that conditions the select statement comparing two fields in the table?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 34):

In addition to what Daniel Ballinger said, the Soap API also does not allow the 'IN' clause in SOQL queries.
It's stupid, but then again, that's 95% of Salesforce.

Comment: That last sentence. Up you go!

Answer (score 7):

SOQL doesn't currently support direct field to field comparison in WHERE clauses. From [Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000187460&language=en_US)

> ## Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL
>
> Knowledge Article Number: 000187460
>
> **Description**
>   I want to execute a query by comparing two fields of the same object in WHERE clause, but I am not able to use a field in
>   the right hand side of a condition in a WHERE clause:
>
> ```
> List<user> users = [SELECT Id,name FROM User WHERE (FirstName != Lastname)];
> ```
>
> The above query returns: "System.QueryException: unexpected token:
>   'Lastname' "
>
> **Resolution**
>   Salesforce doesn't allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query.
>
> To achieve this you may create a formula field that will compare
>   fields and return a value (like true or false) which you may use in a
>   WHERE clause.
>
> So for the above query, you could create a formula field on User
>   object with return type Text e.g. NameCompare, with the formula
>   IF(User.FirstName != User.LastName, 'true', 'false')
>
> Now our query will be:
>
> ```
> List<User> Users = [SELECT id, name FROM User where NameCompare= 'true'];
> ```
>
> Following idea has been posted on ideaexchange portal for allowing
>   field-to-field comparison in SOQL:
>
> https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0

You could create a [formula field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_date_datetime_formula_fields.htm&language=en_US) of type Checkbox to return a boolean:

```
Approved_Date__c > Last_Upload_Date__c
```

Then rewrite your query with your WHERE clause like:

```
SELECT Id  
FROM Price_Agreement_Item__c 
WHERE Approved_Date_Greater_Than_Last_Upload_Date__c = true
```

Be careful about how many rows this will need to scan over. It can't use an index, so will result in a full table scan. If the number of rows gets too large you could get other errors.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40943/query-to-compare-two-date-fields) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions. This answer references a question from there answered by Jesse Altman with comments by Keith C and sfdcfox.

Comment: How do you compare across multiple custom objects?
I have two tables I want to join on by Id, and I'm getting the error: `Error: Field Commission__c does not exist. Check spelling.`

Comment: @BigMoney I'd suggest asking a dedicated question on the [Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/). Include details about what you want to do and what you have tried so far. It's likely that you will need either a lookup or master detail relationship between the two sObjects/tables to perform the join in SOQL.

Answer (score 2):

Another way this can happen is if you copy your query to the command line and run it without escaping the quotes around any string constants.

E.g., this:

```
curl -X GET https://x.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/query?q=SELECT%20COUNT\(\)%20FROM%20YourObj%20WHERE%20field%20!=%20'Good'
```

Should be this:

```
curl -X GET https://x.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/query?q=SELECT%20COUNT\(\)%20FROM%20YourObj%20WHERE%20field%20!=%20%27Good%27
```